# How to transform a str [key] in int before applying it to a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tuples

I'm having in issue here. There goes my code and further explanation. (python3)

```
for doc in cursor: #mongodb cursor
    result_dict = doc #retrieve the doc as dict 
    result = result_dict['final'] #retrieve 'final' that is another 
    dict object that looks like this:
    #{'1': 'Name1',
    # '2': 'Name2',
    # '3': 'Name3'} 
    result_tuple = ()
    for k, v in result.items():
        result_tuple = (v, int(k))
        results.append(result_tuple)
```

The result I'm gathering in my list named "results" is that:

```
#[('Name1', '1'), ('Name2', '2'), ('Name3', '3')
```

I need the key to be transformed into an integer. I can't actually understand why `result_tuple = (v, int(k))` is not transforming the key into an integer.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran your code, seems fine: `[('Name1', 1), ('Name2', 2), ('Name3', 3)]`

Comment: https://eval.in/931245 -

Comment: Can you share how you check items in `results`? Right after loop or maybe after saving/extracting from database?

Comment: I'm checking by printing it in the console. print(results[n]) where n is any number index (it goes to 4000), and every index have the same result: ('NameX', 'Y')

Comment: The code you've shared [when run in isolation](https://ideone.com/KbWjmc) performs perfectly. The problem, therefore, must be in the code you haven't shared. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for information about how and why to create a runnable demonstration program.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help. I restarted conda kernel here and somehow it started worked fine, just as I wanted. Thanks for the support.